# Variacion de tiempo de ejecución entre consultas iguales en SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, java-ee, eclipselink

Buen dia.

Disculpen, tengo una aplicación Java EE que ejecuta consultas a SQL utilizando EntityManager, he notado que, por ejemplo, si hago 1500 veces la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT claseA.Descripcion, claseA.DescripcionIngles 
FROM tablaA ClaseA
WHERE ClaseA.primeraLlaveTabla = @parametro1 and ClaseA.segundaLlaveTabla = @parametro2
```

Algunas veces tarda solamente 20 milisegundos por cada una de las 1500 consultas, pero hay otras ocaciones donde algunas de esas 1500 tardan hasta 120,000 milisegundos.

¿Que motivos pueden haber para que se presenten estas variaciones de tiempo?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Tienes indexada la tabla por los campos de búsqueda?

Comment: red, proxy, firewalls, cache, otras consultas... los motivos pueden ser miles...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!